# Force download in Salesforce HTML Download Link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm adding a link to a Salesforce page with some JavaScript and I want to force the corresponding link to download.  At the moment it's just displaying the image in my browser (current version of Chrome).  Anyone know how to force it to download instead?

```
<a href="https://c.na46.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P..." download="https://c.na46.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P..." target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would remove target="_blank" as that should invoke a new window. Once removed I would expect the download.

There is also a native Security setting page to determine which action to take depending on file type:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_type_security.htm&type=5

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Also, "download" should be the automatically suggested file name, as specified in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: Thanks Glen & fox, tried removing the target and adding download, but Chrome still just shows the preview.  Is this a browser setting that needs updating?  Seems to have the correct behavior when the file isn't an image.